# HOGDescriptor.compute() to get descriptors ,all value of descriptors are positive,what wrong?

Tags: opencv

I used `HOGDescriptor.compute()` to try to get descriptors from  picture (include people), but all value in "vector descriptor" is positive ,I think it impossible. the code is like bellow.

vector descriptors;

```
cv::HOGDescriptor hog_roi(cvSize(width, height), cvSize(16, 16), cvSize(8, 8),cvSize(8, 8), 9);

hog_roi.compute(image_roi2, descriptors, Size(8, 8), Size(0, 0));
```

descriptors I get is like this,and i cant use it to search people :

> SVMDetector: [ 2.66110718e-01, 2.68318206e-01, 2.68318206e-01,
>          2.17726320e-01, 2.51462460e-01, 2.35204116e-01, 7.31925964e-02,
>          5.84346727e-02, 1.52689770e-01, 1.61342099e-01, 1.86763927e-01,
>          1.75199494e-01, 1.68729022e-01, 1.86727673e-01, 7.84099624e-02,
>          4.26537208e-02, 5.24105318e-02, 7.59865493e-02, 3.55061926e-02,
>          6.99645728e-02, 2.19995320e-01, 2.68318206e-01, 2.68318206e-01,
>          1.78995952e-01, 6.61719888e-02, 2.86846794e-02, 2.49618683e-02,
>          3.13862711e-02, 1.32574379e-01, 1.88612297e-01, 2.33186215e-01,
>          2.14858532e-01, 1.11005612e-01, 5.74433915e-02, 5.83223514e-02,
>          5.41414283e-02, 6.72073513e-02, 2.49409005e-01, 2.57455558e-01,
>          1.27111375e-01, 1.64344728e-01, 4.28766869e-02, 4.97805066e-02,......
>
> but opencv demo descriptors like this ,it can work fine.
>       static const float detector[] = {
>          0.05359386f, -0.14721455f, -0.05532170f, 0.05077307f,
>          0.11547081f, -0.04268804f, 0.04635834f, -0.05468199f, 0.08232084f,
>          0.10424068f, -0.02294518f, 0.01108519f, 0.01378693f, 0.11193510f,
>          0.01268418f, 0.08528346f, -0.06309239f, 0.13054633f, 0.08100729f,
>          -0.05209739f, -0.04315529f, 0.09341384f, 0.11035026f, -0.07596218f,
>          -0.05517511f, -0.04465296f, 0.02947334f, 0.04555536f,
>          -3.55954492e-003f, 0.07818956f, 0.07730991f, 0.07890715f, 0.06222893f,
>          0.09001380f, -0.03574381f, 0.03414327f, 0.05677258f, -0.04773581f,
>          0.03746637f, -0.03521175f, 0.06955440f, -0.03849038f, 0.01052293f,......

my picture is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paWEk.png)

Answer (score 0):

My opencv is 2.4.13 , I tried several picture ,all HOG descriptors was positive value,any one can provide a clew? may be the opencv HOG bug? why the demo of people "detector[] " include positive and negative.